# java.lang.ClassCastException: ViewHolderItem cannot be cast to AnotherViewHolderItem

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to filter posts types (for example only images, audio, videos.....) and change the adapter to update items inside recycler view. But for some reason the first time i make any changes to my filter dialog the feature works without problems, but if i try to make any changes for 2nd time inside my dialog, i'm getting an `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.george.socialmeme.ViewHolders.ImageItemViewHolder cannot be cast to com.george.socialmeme.ViewHolders.VideoItemViewHolder
```

**Method that displays the filter dialog:**

```
void showFiltersDialog() {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.posts_filter_bottom_sheet);

    View imagesItem = dialog.findViewById(R.id.view23);
    View videosItem = dialog.findViewById(R.id.view21);
    View soundsItem = dialog.findViewById(R.id.view22);
    View textItem = dialog.findViewById(R.id.view20);
    Button applyFiltersBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.apply_filters);

    if (!imagesItemSelected[0]) {
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView30).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!videosItemSelected[0]) {
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView32).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!soundsItemSelected[0]) {
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView34).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!textItemSelected[0]) {
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView36).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    imagesItem.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (imagesItemSelected[0]) {
            imagesItemSelected[0] = false;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView30).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            imagesItemSelected[0] = true;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView30).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    videosItem.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (videosItemSelected[0]) {
            videosItemSelected[0] = false;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView32).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            videosItemSelected[0] = true;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView32).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    soundsItem.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (soundsItemSelected[0]) {
            soundsItemSelected[0] = false;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView34).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            soundsItemSelected[0] = true;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView34).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    textItem.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (textItemSelected[0]) {
            textItemSelected[0] = false;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView36).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            textItemSelected[0] = true;
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView36).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    applyFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        filteredPostsArrayList.clear();
        applyFiltersBtn.setText("Filtering...");
        applyFiltersBtn.setEnabled(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        for (PostModel postModel : postModelArrayList) {

                if (postModel.getPostType().equals("image")) {
                    if (imagesItemSelected[0]) {
                        filteredPostsArrayList.add(postModel);
                    }
                }

                if (postModel.getPostType().equals("video")) {
                    if (videosItemSelected[0]) {
                        filteredPostsArrayList.add(postModel);
                    }
                }

                if (postModel.getPostType().equals("audio")) {
                    if (soundsItemSelected[0]) {
                        filteredPostsArrayList.add(postModel);
                    }
                }

                if (postModel.getPostType().equals("text")) {
                    if (textItemSelected[0]) {
                        filteredPostsArrayList.add(postModel);
                    }
                }

        }

        // Update RecyclerView adapter
        recyclerAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter(filteredPostsArrayList, getContext(), getActivity());
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Add post's of the month view as RecyclerView item
        // to avoid using ScrollView
        PostModel postsOfTheMonthView = new PostModel();
        postsOfTheMonthView.setPostType("postsOfTheMonth");
        filteredPostsArrayList.add(postsOfTheMonthView);

        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        dialog.dismiss();

    });

    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM);

}
```

**My PostRecyclerAdapter class:**

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    List<PostModel> postList;
    Context context;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("video")) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("postsOfTheMonth")) {
            return 2;
        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("audio")) {
            return 3;
        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("text")) {
            return 4;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public PostRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<PostModel> postModelArrayList, Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.postList = postModelArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == 1) {
            return new VideoItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_post_item, parent, false));
        }
        if (viewType == 2) {
            return new PostsOfTheMonthItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts_of_the_month_view_item, parent, false));
        }
        if (viewType == 3) {
            return new AudioItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audio_post_item, parent, false));
        }
        if (viewType == 4) {
            return new PostTextItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_post_item, parent, false));
        }
        return new ImageItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_post_item, parent, false));
    }

    // Release ExoPlayer when a video item is recycled
    // to avoid player errors on other video items inside RecyclerView
    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        if (postList.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).getPostType().equals("video")) {
            VideoItemViewHolder videoViewHolder = (VideoItemViewHolder) holder;
            videoViewHolder.andExoPlayerView.getPlayer().release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        DatabaseReference likeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("likes");
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("postsOfTheMonth")) {
            PostsOfTheMonthItemViewHolder viewHolder = (PostsOfTheMonthItemViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.setContext(context);
        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("text")) {

            // Bind audio view holder
            PostTextItemViewHolder textItemViewHolder = (PostTextItemViewHolder) holder;
            textItemViewHolder.setContext(context);

            if (HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {
                textItemViewHolder.commentsCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textItemViewHolder.postOptionsButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textItemViewHolder.openCommentsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textItemViewHolder.shareBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                if (user.getUid().equals(postList.get(position).getAuthorID())) {
                    textItemViewHolder.followBtnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            // check if post is liked or not
            likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {

                        // check if current post is liked from this user
                        if (snapshot.child(textItemViewHolder.postID).hasChild(user.getUid())) {
                            // post is liked form this user
                            textItemViewHolder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like_filled);
                            textItemViewHolder.isPostLiked = true;
                        } else {
                            // post is not liked from this user
                            textItemViewHolder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                            textItemViewHolder.isPostLiked = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        textItemViewHolder.like_btn.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            textItemViewHolder.postID = postList.get(position).getId();
            textItemViewHolder.username.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
            textItemViewHolder.postAuthorID = postList.get(position).getAuthorID();
            textItemViewHolder.like_counter_tv.setText(postList.get(position).getLikes());
            textItemViewHolder.commentsCount.setText(postList.get(position).getCommentsCount());

            // Load Title and content for the post
            textItemViewHolder.postTitle.setText(postList.get(position).getPostTitle());
            textItemViewHolder.postContentText.setText(postList.get(position).getPostContentText());

            // Load profile picture
            String profilePictureUrl = postList.get(position).getProfileImgUrl();
            if (profilePictureUrl != null) {
                if (!profilePictureUrl.equals("none")) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(profilePictureUrl).into(textItemViewHolder.profilePicture);
                }
            }

            textItemViewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("post_url", postList.get(position).getImgUrl());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Audio URL copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });

        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("audio")) {

            // Bind audio view holder
            AudioItemViewHolder audioViewHolder = (AudioItemViewHolder) holder;
            audioViewHolder.setContext(context);

            if (HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {
                audioViewHolder.commentsCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                audioViewHolder.postOptionsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                audioViewHolder.openCommentsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                audioViewHolder.shareBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                if (user.getUid().equals(postList.get(position).getAuthorID())) {
                    audioViewHolder.followBtnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            // check if post is liked or not
            likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {

                        // check if current post is liked from this user
                        if (snapshot.child(audioViewHolder.postID).hasChild(user.getUid())) {
                            // post is liked form this user
                            audioViewHolder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like_filled);
                            audioViewHolder.isPostLiked = true;
                        } else {
                            // post is not liked from this user
                            audioViewHolder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                            audioViewHolder.isPostLiked = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // disable like button
                        audioViewHolder.likeBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            audioViewHolder.postID = postList.get(position).getId();
            audioViewHolder.usernameTV.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
            audioViewHolder.postAuthorID = postList.get(position).getAuthorID();
            audioViewHolder.likesCounter.setText(postList.get(position).getLikes());
            audioViewHolder.audioURL = postList.get(position).getImgUrl();
            audioViewHolder.audioName.setText(postList.get(position).getAudioName());
            audioViewHolder.commentsCounter.setText(postList.get(position).getCommentsCount());

            // Load audio source
            audioViewHolder.audioPlayerView.withUrl(postList.get(position).getImgUrl());

            // Load profile picture
            String profilePictureUrl = postList.get(position).getProfileImgUrl();
            if (profilePictureUrl != null) {
                if (!profilePictureUrl.equals("none")) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(profilePictureUrl).into(audioViewHolder.profilePicture);
                }
            }

            audioViewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("post_url", postList.get(position).getImgUrl());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Audio URL copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });

        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("video")) {

            // bind video view holder
            VideoItemViewHolder videoViewHolder = (VideoItemViewHolder) holder;
            videoViewHolder.setContext(context);

            if (HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {
                videoViewHolder.commentsCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoViewHolder.postOptionsButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoViewHolder.commentsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoViewHolder.shareBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                if (user.getUid().equals(postList.get(position).getAuthorID())) {
                    videoViewHolder.followBtnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            // check if post is liked or not
            likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {

                        // check if current post is liked from this user
                        if (snapshot.child(videoViewHolder.postID).hasChild(user.getUid())) {
                            // post is liked form this user
                            videoViewHolder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like_filled);
                            videoViewHolder.isPostLiked = true;
                        } else {
                            // post is not liked from this user
                            videoViewHolder.isPostLiked = false;
                            videoViewHolder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // disable like button
                        videoViewHolder.like_btn.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            videoViewHolder.postID = postList.get(position).getId();
            videoViewHolder.username.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
            videoViewHolder.postAuthorID = postList.get(position).getAuthorID();
            videoViewHolder.like_counter_tv.setText(postList.get(position).getLikes());
            videoViewHolder.videoURL = postList.get(position).getImgUrl();
            videoViewHolder.commentsCount.setText(postList.get(position).getCommentsCount());

            // Load video source
            ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
            MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(postList.get(position).getImgUrl());
            player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
            player.prepare();
            videoViewHolder.andExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

            player.addAnalyticsListener(new AnalyticsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(@NonNull EventTime eventTime, @NonNull PlaybackException error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("EXOPLAYER_ERROR", "" + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Load profile picture
            String profilePictureUrl = postList.get(position).getProfileImgUrl();
            if (profilePictureUrl != null) {
                if (!profilePictureUrl.equals("none")) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(profilePictureUrl).into(videoViewHolder.profilePicture);
                }
            }

            videoViewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("post_url", postList.get(position).getImgUrl());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Video URL copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });

        }

        if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("image")) {

            // bind image view holder
            ImageItemViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageItemViewHolder) holder;
            imageViewHolder.setContext(context);

            if (HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {
                imageViewHolder.commentsCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageViewHolder.show_comments_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageViewHolder.showPostOptionsButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageViewHolder.shareBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                if (user.getUid().equals(postList.get(position).getAuthorID())) {
                    imageViewHolder.followBtnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            // check if post is liked or not from the user
            likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!HomeActivity.singedInAnonymously) {

                        // check if current post is liked from this user
                        if (snapshot.child(imageViewHolder.postID).hasChild(user.getUid())) {
                            // post is liked form this user
                            imageViewHolder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like_filled);
                            imageViewHolder.isPostLiked = true;
                        } else {
                            // post is not liked from this user
                            imageViewHolder.isPostLiked = false;
                            imageViewHolder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        }
                    } else {
                        imageViewHolder.like_btn.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            imageViewHolder.postID = postList.get(position).getId();
            imageViewHolder.username.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
            imageViewHolder.postAuthorID = postList.get(position).getAuthorID();
            imageViewHolder.like_counter_tv.setText(postList.get(position).getLikes());
            imageViewHolder.commentsCount.setText(postList.get(position).getCommentsCount());

            Picasso.get().load(postList.get(position).getImgUrl()).into(imageViewHolder.postImg, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    imageViewHolder.loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Can't load this image: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            imageViewHolder.postImageURL = postList.get(position).getImgUrl();

            // Load profile picture
            String profilePictureUrl = postList.get(position).getProfileImgUrl();
            if (profilePictureUrl != null) {
                if (!profilePictureUrl.equals("none")) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(profilePictureUrl).into(imageViewHolder.profileImage);
                }
            }

            imageViewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("post_url", postList.get(position).getImgUrl());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Image URL copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });

        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to cast item which is not an instance of VideoItemViewHolder to VideoItemViewHolder. Before making cast, check if the item is an instance of VideoItemViewHolder:

```
if(holder instanceof VideoItemViewHolder){
   VideoItemViewHolder videoViewHolder = (VideoItemViewHolder) holder;
   //Do your stuff...
} else {
   //Cast cannot be done
}
```